# What is the proper way to log in to ECR?

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ecr

Currently, I have this command in my bash script for building & pushing an image to Amazon ECR

```
docker login -u AWS -p "$(aws ecr get-login-password)" "https://$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text).dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Which gives the warning **"WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin."**

How can I change this command to not give the warning? Is this really insecure?

Comment: Yes, because the password is briefly visible in the process lists for any process to read.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tinkering around this seems to work well:

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin "https://$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text).dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Hrm this fails with `Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://longnumber.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61854312/4989929

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the AWS CLI is already configured correctly, for example with:

```
aws configure
```

Then just call the following:

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin "https://$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text).dkr.ecr.$(aws configure get region).amazonaws.com"
```

The previous command `aws ecr get-login` automatically resolved the Account ID and region. The above command does that explicitly:

```
$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text)
```

*(as per @Moak's answer, thank you)*

and:

```
$(aws configure get region)
```

to get the region.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to log in to ECR is to use the command produced by `aws ecr get-login`.

Comment: That's a deprecated command not available to us

Answer (score 2):

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region cn-northwest-1)
```

replace `cn-northwest-1` as your region.

Comment: It might work, but that command is deprecated

Comment: @Moak where does AWS say `aws ecr get-login` is deprecated?

Comment: In the official docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html